# How to let other people use ssh to connect to my computer?

Tags: macos, bash, ssh

My operating system is Mac OS X.
I want to use bash command to let other people use ssh to connect my computer.
How do I do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. set up a user account for them on your computer;
2. allow logon privileges for the user.

OS X Server puts a pretty GUI face on doing this.

Answer (score 0):

You need to edit the /etc/ssh/sshd_config file and add the user to the end of the file with the following syntax. Also that user will need to be a valid user on the local machine or found in a bound directory service.

```
vi /etc/ssh/sshd_config
AllowUsers username1
```

There are other settings you can set in regards to ciphers and keys that improve security. Also you may need to modify any firewall settings that may be in place.